# Creating Beautiful box

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, tikz-styles, mdframed

I would like to create

- **(blue!70) box contains method of how I use geogebra**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=Method]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1}
\lipsum
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your `itemize` environment and your image within two minipages side by side.

The color inside the box is set with the option: `colback=<any_color_you_like>`.

If you have different kinds of boxes, one choice is to create a style (I called it `mybeatiful`) and use it only when needed.

There is also the possibility to create a new `tcolorbox` (I called it `mybox`, this is more convenient because you have to write less).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}
\tcbset{
  mybeautiful/.style={
      sharp corners=all,
      enhanced,
      breakable,
      colback=cyan!20,
      colframe=blue!75!black,
      colbacktitle=blue,
      coltitle=white,
      left skip={.20\linewidth},
      attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-.2\linewidth, yshift=-40pt},
      boxed title style={
          sharp corners=all,       }
      }
}

% definition of a new tcolorbox whic uses the style:
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{ 
    mybeautiful,  
    title    = #2,
    #1,
    }


\begin{document}
First option: using a style directly:
\begin{tcolorbox}[mybeautiful,title=Method]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item I hope
\item this is
\item what you want
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item I hope
\item this is
\item what you want
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

Second option (more convenient) a new tcolorbox:
\begin{mybox}{Method}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item I hope
\item this is
\item what you want
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item I hope
\item this is
\item what you want
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please add color inside the box

Comment: @Educ Done, I set `colback=cyan!20`, but you can use any color you like, of course.

Comment: please one last request could you please make it local by creating new tcolorbox because it's affect my other box

Comment: @Educ Done, see my renewed answer, you can create a style and use it only when needed.

Comment: @Educ Please note that `mybeautiful` is also in the `tcolorbox` options

Comment: @Educ It's more convenient if you create a new tcolorbox, see `mybox` in my example.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Very good answer with the approach of `minipage`. +1.

Answer (score 6):

I hope it goes well with `blue!70`! It is only a bit of code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand*\keystroke[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(key.base)]
    \node[%
      draw=white!20!gray!10,
      fill=lightgray,
      drop shadow={shadow xshift=0.25ex,shadow yshift=-0.25ex,fill=lightgray,opacity=0.4},
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      inner sep=1pt,
      line width=0.5pt,
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily
    ](key) {#1\strut}
  ;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cyan!10,colframe=blue!70,title=Method]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
\caption{image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1] with Blaaaaaaa \keystroke{Ctrl}+\keystroke{V} 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you but I really want is almost the same Box that I asked for

Comment: When I add itemize the position of image move to the bottom of box

Comment: @Educ I am not a very good LaTeX user like many others. If you look at my answers, they are often very synthetic because it takes at least two hours to create a suitable job, at least for me. CarlaTeX is a very good user. I have also added to you the keyboard characters with a suitable gradient.

Comment: I really apperciated that +1 already